# Overload HTTP POST

Tags: c#, swagger, overloading

Say me please, why I do get error: Fetch error
Internal Server Error http://127.0.0.1:5001/swagger/v1/swagger.json

The part of the code where the error occurs:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ActionName("CreatePostWithMediaId")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePost([FromForm]string? heading, 
            [FromForm]string content, 
            [FromForm] int tagId, 
            [FromForm] int? mediaId = null)
        {
            content = content.Replace(@"\n", "\n");
            Post post = new Post()
            {
                heading = heading,
                content = content,
                tag = tagId,
                mediaId = mediaId,
                date = DateTime.UtcNow,
            };
            _unitOfWork.PostRepository.Create(post);
            _unitOfWork.Save();
            return Ok(post);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("CreatePostWithFile")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePost([FromForm] string? heading,
            [FromForm] string content,
            [FromForm] int tagId,
            [FromForm] IFormFile? file = null)
        {
            content = content.Replace(@"\n", "\n");
            var mediaResult = await _fileManager.UploadFile(file);
            Post post = new Post()
            {
                heading = heading,
                content = content,
                tag = tagId,
                mediaId = mediaResult.id,
                date = DateTime.UtcNow,
            };
            _unitOfWork.PostRepository.Create(post);
            _unitOfWork.Save();
            return Ok(post);
        }
```

I will be grateful for any of your help

Comment: You'd better use different names of methods instead of relying on the action name property

Comment: @Bellash that is, in this case, the overload can not be done?

Comment: @Fa4stik overloading is not very relevant in case of ASP routes. It seems that swagger generator can't distinguish two actions using the provided attributes.

Comment: @GuruStron I understand, this is not cool :( 
Thanks very a loot for help!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution, but it may be useful to someone:

```
[HttpPost("{heading}/{content}/{tagId:int}/{mediaId:int}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePost([FromForm]string? heading, 
            [FromForm]string content, 
            [FromForm] int tagId, 
            [FromForm] int? mediaId = null)
        {
            content = content.Replace(@"\n", "\n");
            Post post = new Post()
            {
                heading = heading,
                content = content,
                tag = tagId,
                mediaId = mediaId,
                date = DateTime.UtcNow,
            };
            _unitOfWork.PostRepository.Create(post);
            _unitOfWork.Save();
            return Ok(post);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePost([FromForm] string? heading,
            [FromForm] string content,
            [FromForm] int tagId,
            [FromForm] IFormFile? file = null)
        {
            content = content.Replace(@"\n", "\n");
            var mediaResult = await _fileManager.UploadFile(file);
            Post post = new Post()
            {
                heading = heading,
                content = content,
                tag = tagId,
                mediaId = mediaResult.id,
                date = DateTime.UtcNow,
            };
            _unitOfWork.PostRepository.Create(post);
            _unitOfWork.Save();
            return Ok(post);
        }
```